# Converting subclass to jsonb

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jsonb

Im new with Java, hibernate, postgres.

Im trying to write to a table with (not so much) complex data and Im keep getting exceptions. ill be happy for some guidance.

This is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT exists public.my_table (
 id             uuid primary key default uuid_generate_v4(),
 description     text,
 content         jsonb
);
```

The main issue is with the `content` field and converting it to `jsonb` type.

This is the entity:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "my_table")
    public class MyClassEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private UUID id;

    @Type(type = "text")
    @Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @Embedded
    @Convert(converter = SubClassConverter.class)
    @Column(name = "content", columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private SubClass content;

    public void setId (UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public UUID getId () {
        return this.id;
    }
    public void setDesctiption (String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getDescription () {
        return this.description;
    }
    public void setContent SubClass content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
    public SubClass getContent () {
        return this.content;
    }
    }
```

This is the `SubClass`:

```
    @Embeddable
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public class SubClass {

    @JsonProperty("param_a")
    private String param_a;

    @JsonProperty("param_b")
    private String param_b;

    @JsonProperty("regex")
    private boolean regex;

    public SubClass(){}

    public SubClass(String param_a, String param_b, boolean regex){
        this.param_a = param_a;
        this.param_b = param_b;
        this.regex = regex;
    }

    public SubClass(SubClass subClass) {
        this(
                subClass.getParamA(),
                subClass.getParamB(),
                subClass.getRegex()
        );
    }

    //getters + setters
    }
```

This is the converter:

```
    public class SubClassConverter implements AttributeConverter<SubClass, String>  {
   
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public SubClassConverter() {
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumnSubClassConverter (SubClass in) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(in);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to convert", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public SubClass convertToEntityAttribute(String joined) {
        
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(joined)) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            SubClass metadata = objectMapper.readValue(joined, SubClass.class);
            if (metadata == null) return null;
            return metadata;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    }
```

this is the repository:

```
    @Repository
    public interface MyClassRepository extends CrudRepository<MyClassEntity, UUID> {

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "insert into my_table (description, content) " +
            "values (:description, cast(:content as jsonb))", nativeQuery = true)
    void insertMyClass(@Param("description") String description,
                       @Param("content") SubClass content);

    }
```

This is the exception I get:

> 8480 SEVERE [main] --- org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication: Application run failed
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Convert placed on Embedded attribute must define (sub)attributeName
>
> 8480 SEVERE [main] --- org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@73ee04c8] to prepare test instance [com.gms.model.services.MyClassServiceTest@39695803]
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Convert placed on Embedded attribute must define (sub)attributeName

I must say that I tried to google it and fix it. but each "fix" gave me the same or other error.

Im kind of stuck now and ill be happy for help

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're using `@Embedded` to handle a `jsonb` column parser.

> The JPA annotation @Embedded is used to embed a type into another entity.

Embedding entity columns and mapping of to a single database table. You can refer to this [doc](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-embedded-embeddable) for more info.

Your case if you're using Hibernate 6, this is the only thing you need.

```
public class MyClassEntity {
    @Column(name = "content", columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
    private SubClass content;
}
```

For Hibernate 4 and 5, you need to implement `UserType` for it

```
public class SubClassType implements UserType<SubClass> {
 
    public static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
     
    @Override
    public int getSqlType() {
        return SqlTypes.JSON;
    }
 
    @Override
    public Class<SubClass> returnedClass() {
        return SubClass.class;
    }
 
    // implementations of nullSafeGet, deepCopy...
}
```

Also, declare it as `Custom type` on class level. This is the [documentation](https://thorben-janssen.com/persist-postgresqls-jsonb-data-type-hibernate/). I hope it helps.